# Table in Matplotlib hiding values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to show the values in the table but they are hidden somehow, how do I make them appear again? I always have trouble with pasting code, so I now just screenshot the code.

```
#Display top matches in table and save as image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = plt.imread(r'C:\Users\alexr\Desktop\Analysis\PSL\Laduma_Analytics\LA Structure Logo & Process\LA_Pitch_Process.jpg')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img, extent=[-5, 80, -5, 30])

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('grey')
#fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')
text_color = 'black'

table = ax.table(cellText=Player_Name_Similarity.iloc[0:15,:].values, colLabels=Player_Name_Similarity.columns, loc='center', cellLoc='center', fontsize=7, zorder=2)
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(7)

#Add image title
ax.set_title(Player + ' - Player Similarity in DSTV Premiership'
             '\nPlayers who are most similar based on our model', 
          loc='center', fontsize=10, color=text_color)

#Add image description
#ax.title('\nPlayers who are most similar based on our model', 
#             loc='center', fontsize=8, style='italic', color=text_color)

#Add copyright details
ax.text(0.00, 0.1, 'Created by: Laduma Analytics', verticalalignment='bottom', horizontalalignment='left', 
        transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=7)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO. You can format the code using the `{}` button.

Comment: Found solution as to my text colour was somehow defaulting to white and thus hidden in the table.